# Running pyc files using Command Line

Tags: python, apache-spark, command-line, pyspark, bytecode

I am running my python files (containing spark context also) in .py format with the following command

```
CALL %SPARK_HOME%\bin\spark-submit2 D:\KOCKPIT\DB0E0\src\Location.py
```

which are running successfully. In order to keep my files in Bytecode format i changed my file format to .pyc using the below command

```
%PYTHONPATH%\python -m packageall -f src
```

Now when I am trying to run my new created .pyc files with the same command then I am getting the following below error.

[image]

After some research online I found that using **--py-files** in the batch command will work for python files

[image]

Even though my py files are running good, but as per the error in the execution of .pyc files i included the statement

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

in my code then also getting the same error.

My files are basically pyspark files in the output format of .py.

I am open to posting my code also in case if required in solving this.

Comment: missing resource ! check/use a valid path,`file:/D/KOCKPIT/` isn't valid directory, this path work under browser type file access, but how make a application access ?

Comment: Hi, this is a valid directory as my .py files are running fine from this directory only.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename `xx.pyc` to `xx.py`. `--py-files` is not needed. I think this error occurs since `spark-submit` tries to find `.py` no matter what.